# How to remove keys and values in telemetry of things board?

Tags: thingsboard

I'm sending telemetry data in to things board as below and posted correctly

'''
{
"Data_X" : "test_datax",
"Data_Y" : "test_datay,
"Data" : "test_data"
}
'''
Now need to remove data key and value as it was sent incorrectly(including all historical data)

Anyone has any idea how to do ?. I do have things board TimescaleDB access. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete them using API, dont need to make queries directly to database.

First, open your thinsgboard api console: https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/.

Then, open the telemetry-controller and make this request:
[image]